# java public static and private static, stringbuilder

Tags: java, private, stringbuilder, public-method

Below is the code i am trying to compile, it seems that i have problem with using a method within a method and unable to close the first method. Thus, unable to compile the program. Furthermore, im not sure if the Stringbuilder i've applied is correct or not as i cannot compile.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class tryingtoedit{

public static void main( String[] args ){
int block[][] = new int[gridsize][gridsize];
int row = 0;   // The variable assigned for counting rows
int column = 0; // The variable assigned for counting columns
int blockRow,blockColumn;
int score = 0;
final int gridsize = 3;
String inputRow, inputColumn;

//random a set of number
int randomSet[] = new int[100];
for(int i=0;i<randomSet.length;i++){
    randomSet[i] = (int) (Math.random() * gridsize * gridsize) + 1;
}


int round = 0 ;//for counting the round of the game
while( true ){
    ++round;

    //print out the title and score
    System.out.println( "-------------------------" );
    System.out.println( "Divided by 10 - Mini Game" );
    System.out.printf( "----  Score:%8d  ----\n\n", score );

    //show game board
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < gridsize; i++) {
        sb.append(String.format("%4d", i));
}

    //display the coming value
    System.out.printf( "Coming value : %d > %d > %d \n\n", randomSet[round], randomSet[(round + 1)], randomSet[(round + 2)] );



    //check over checking
    private static final boolean isComplete(int[][] grid) {
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
                if (grid[row][col] == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true; // all celss have values.
}
                System.out.println( "------  Game Over  ------" );
                //continue check
                if(isComplete(block)){
                int ContinueCheck = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to    continue ?", "Continue?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if( ContinueCheck == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    //initialize the game board
                    for(row=0;row<block.length;row++)
                        for(column=0;column<block.length;column++)
                            block[row][column]=0;
                    continue;
                }else{if(ContinueCheck == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
                    System.out.println( "-------------------------" );
                    System.out.println("Good Bye !");
                    break;}
                }
            }


    //input value
    while(true){
        inputRow = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "The number of row you want to put the number" );
        blockRow = Integer.parseInt(inputRow);
        inputColumn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "The number of column you want to put the number" );
        blockColumn = Integer.parseInt(inputColumn);
        if(blockRow>=block.length || blockRow<0 || blockColumn>=block.length || blockColumn<0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "The block you want to enter the number does not exist." , "Error" , JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
            continue;
        }else{
            if(block[blockRow][blockColumn]!=0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "The block you want to enter the number has been entered an number." , "Error" , JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
                continue;
            }else{
                block[blockRow][blockColumn] = randomSet[round];
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    //score got check
    int modSumBlock[] = new int[gridsize + gridsize + 2]; // rows, columns, and diagonals
    for (int row = 0; row < gridsize; row++) {
        modSumBlock[       0 + row] = getRowScore(block, row);
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < gridsize; col++) {
        modSumBlock[gridsize + col] = getColumnScore(block, col);
    }
    modSumBlock[gridsize + gridsize]     = getSlashDiagonalScore(block);
    modSumBlock[gridsize + gridsize + 1] = getBackslashDiagonalScore(block);
    //all 'if' is used for checking if all block in the same row/column/diagonal are filled in number

    //counting how many score got and where should be cleared by 8bit (in decimal)
    int scoreCount = 0;
    for(int n=0;n<8;n++){
        if(modSumBlock[n]==0){
            score += 10;
            scoreCount += (int) Math.pow(2,n);
        }else{
            continue;
        }
    }

    //start clear game board
    if(scoreCount>=128){
        block[0][2] = 0;
        block[1][1] = 0;
        block[2][0] = 0;
        scoreCount -= 128;
    }
    if(scoreCount>=64){
        block[0][0] = 0;
        block[1][1] = 0;
        block[2][2] = 0;
        scoreCount -= 64;
    }
    if(scoreCount>=32){
        block[0][2] = 0;
        block[1][2] = 0;
        block[2][2] = 0;
        scoreCount -= 32;
    }
    if(scoreCount>=16){
        block[0][1] = 0;
        block[1][1] = 0;
        block[2][1] = 0;
        scoreCount -= 16;
    }
    if(scoreCount>=8){
        block[0][0] = 0;
        block[1][0] = 0;
        block[2][0] = 0;
        scoreCount -= 8;
    }
    if(scoreCount>=4){
        block[2][0] = 0;
        block[2][1] = 0;
        block[2][2] = 0;
        scoreCount -= 4;
    }
    if(scoreCount>=2){
        block[1][0] = 0;
        block[1][1] = 0;
        block[1][2] = 0;
        scoreCount -= 2;
    }
    if(scoreCount>=1){
        block[0][0] = 0;
        block[0][1] = 0;
        block[0][2] = 0;
        scoreCount -= 1;
    }
}
}
}
```

The error message im getting

```
tryingtoedit.java:42: error: illegal start of expression
    private static final boolean isComplete(int[][] grid) {
    ^
tryingtoedit.java:42: error: illegal start of expression
    private static final boolean isComplete(int[][] grid) {
            ^
tryingtoedit.java:42: error: ';' expected
    private static final boolean isComplete(int[][] grid) {
                  ^
tryingtoedit.java:42: error: ';' expected
    private static final boolean isComplete(int[][] grid) {
                                           ^
tryingtoedit.java:42: error: ';' expected
    private static final boolean isComplete(int[][] grid) {
                                                        ^
5 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Use an IDE, format your code.

Comment: *"trying to compile"* Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Comment: Read the error message. If you don't understand it, post it.

Comment: error message is illegal start of expression with private static final boolean isComplete(int[][] grid) {

Comment: You can't put a method inside another method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing brackets and/or have misplaced them. Check your code again.

For example your `isComplete` method is inside a while loop of the `main` method.

It helps if you use correct indentation to figure out where you need the brackets placed.

Comment: sorry new to programming. I've tried closing the second method "Is"Complete" by putting the end brackets, however still getting the error of illegal start of expression for the second method.

Comment: Right now you have placed your `isComplete` method inside your main method, which is not allowed. So before your `isComplete` method, you need to close all brackets from the main method. Just count them, the number of open brackets has to be equal the number of closed brackets.

Comment: if i close my main method, doesnt it mean my variables cannot be used out the end of main method?

Comment: the ones you define in your main method can only be used in that method.